# How do I compare 2 percentage gains?

Tags: math, statistics, average, data-mining

I have a stats question.

Below is the secnario
Person 1 has 2 stock transaction in his portfolio
Symbol : A, buyPrice : $10.00, sellPrice: $12.00
Symbol : B, buyPrice : $50.00, sellPrice: $55.00

Person 2 has 3 stock transaction in his portfolio
Symbol : C, buyPrice : $20.00, sellPrice: $25.00
Symbol : D, buyPrice : $45.00, sellPrice: $40.00
Symbol : E, buyPrice : $70.00, sellPrice: $71.00

With only the above information, how do I know if person1 has higeher percent gain OR person2 ?
Again,
1. the info I have is limited
2. I donot need the gain in $, just in percent.
3. It doesn't need to be accurate, approx values will suffice.

I guess we can't use average in this. So I am not sure what is a better metric here.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious would be:

[image: percent]

This would yield for person1=0.1166 and for person2=0.0074.